# I want to find values which lies between 25th- 50th percentile in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have 80*80 matrix of PM10, i want to find all the values which lie between percentile 25th-50th. How to write a code for it?

I have changed my code like this:

```
for i=1:80;
for j=1:80;
t(i,j) = prctile(ans(i,j),25) > ans(i,j) | prctile(ans(i,j),75) < ans(i,j);
out(i,j) = t(i,j);
out(ans) = nan;
end;
end;
```

But , the output showing all the grids value as zero. Can someone please rectify my code. Thank you.

Comment: with `prctile`.

Comment: Earlier i have written a code like this:

for i=1:80;
for  j=1:80;
percentile_25(i,j) = (PM10(i,j)<prctile(PM10(i,j),25));
percentile_50(i,j) = (PM10(i,j)>prctile(PM10(i,j),50));
end;
end;

But with this i am not getting the values that lies between the given percentile.

Comment: Please attach your code to the question itself, and format it so we can help you

Comment: Do you want 25th and 50th percentiles of all the pixels in the image?

Comment: I want all the values which lie between 25th -50th percentile in my 2d matrix of size 80*80. So if i write a code which says find values ranging from 25th percentile to 50th percentile and others values which does not lie in this percentile group will be named as NaN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no reason to loop over the matrix elements, because `prctile` works on the whole data. After that, use logical indexing to directly turn all the rest of the values to NaN:

```
p=prctile(PM10(:),[25 50]);
PM10(PM10<p(1) | PM10>p(2))=NaN;
```